# Ninject Dependency Injection on Action Method Parameters in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I would like to use NInject.MVC3 to resolve which concrete class to instantiate when calling an Action method on a controller.  So for example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IMyModelInterface model)
    {
        // do something

        return View();
    }
```

Obviously without dependency injection, MVC3 could not instantiate the IMyModelInterface, but I could bind that interface to a concrete class that implements this interface.

I have tried this and just get the error from the MVC framework trying to instantiate the interface.

So, first of all, is this a bad thing to attempt to do?

If it is not a stupid thing to do, how do I do it?

If it is a bad thing to do, how else should I do this.  I have considered using a ViewModel then copying the parameters across? I am slightly reluctant to do this, as my model contains all the nice validation attributes for the view to use - and would have to duplicate this in the ViewModel, which seems to add maintenance overhead.

I have seen the SO question with [doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859482/autofac-dependency-injection-on-action-method-parameters-asp-mvc3) using Autofac.

I am using the most recent versions of NInject and NInject.MVC3 from the Nuget package.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it injected to the Action method? Why can't you use constructor injection on the controller?

Comment: I could use constructor injection if I was injecting dependency on some service, but I am trying to use DI on the model, so I can switch from one implementation of the model to another.  I am now slightly regretting that choice now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninject does not allow you to inject dependencies in methods like that, as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091238/how-do-you-use-method-injection-with-ninject).
You should inject your dependencies through controller's constructor, properties or setter methods.

Comment: Oh well, I will either wrap my model interface in another class to achieve this behavior, or I will rearrange my architecture to allow constructor injection on the controller - thanks.

Comment: @Nelson, could you look at this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971605/custom-authorizeattribute-ninject-property-injection-doesnt-work-injected-prop

Answer (score 4):

You could probably implement your own model binder to do this.

Subclass DefaultModelBinder, override CreateModel and use Ninject in this method return the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks StanK - when I get more confident with the default patterns that NInject encourages, I might try that approach.